# Proguard in android studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-proguard

I have an `apk` with `31MB`size then I used from `proguard` and it is `30MB` now.

**Problem :** When I upload `apk` on google play the size of `apk` increase to `57MB`

What can I do ?

Here is my `gradle` :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ss.sss.sss"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "41b72f81-0a8b-4ebd-86be-539e2e65113d",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "160823840785"]
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
                // but continue the build even when errors are found:
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
    implementation 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.3'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material-community:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
#For eventBus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
#For sqliteassethelper
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}
#For proguard-support-v7-appcompat
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
#For com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1
-keep class com.shockwave.**
#For butterknife
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }

# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
#For OneSignal
-dontwarn com.onesignal.**

# These 2 methods are called with reflection.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient {
    void connect();
    void disconnect();
}


-keep class com.onesignal.ActivityLifecycleListenerCompat** {*;}


# Observer backcall methods are called with reflection
-keep class com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionState {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSPermissionState);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.OSPermissionChangedInternalObserver {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSPermissionState);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionChangedInternalObserver {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionState);
}

-keep class ** implements com.onesignal.OSPermissionObserver {
    void onOSPermissionChanged(com.onesignal.OSPermissionStateChanges);
}

-keep class ** implements com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionObserver {
    void onOSSubscriptionChanged(com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionStateChanges);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.AdwHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.ApexHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.AsusHomeLauncher { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.DefaultBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.EverythingMeHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.HuaweiHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.LGHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.NewHtcHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.NovaHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.OPPOHomeBader { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.SamsungHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.SonyHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.VivoHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.XiaomiHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.ZukHomeBadger { <init>(...); }


-dontwarn com.amazon.**

# Proguard ends up removing this class even if it is used in AndroidManifest.xml so force keeping it.
-keep public class com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler {*;}

-keep class com.onesignal.JobIntentService$* {*;}

-keep class com.onesignal.OneSignalUnityProxy {*;}

#For iconify
-keep class com.joanzapata.iconify.** { *; }
########--------Retrofit + RxJava--------#########
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.retrofit.RetrofitJackson**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn retrofit.**

-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
   long producerNode;
   long consumerNode;
}


# ALSO REMEMBER KEEPING YOUR MODEL CLASSES
-keep class com.your.package.model.** { *; }
#For volley
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher {
    void processRequest();
}
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher {
    void processRequest();
}
#For piccaso and okHttp
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
#For glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

# for DexGuard only
#-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule

#For support-vector-drawable
-keep class VectorPlay.** { *; }
-keep interface VectorPlay.**
-keep enum VectorPlay.**

#For android.support:design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

#For cardview-v7
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawable { *; }

#For recyclerview-v7
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager {
    public <init>(...);
}
# For constraint
-dontwarn android.support.constraint.**
-keep class android.support.constraint.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.constraint.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.constraint.R$* { *; }
```

Comment: you are using multiple network transmitting libs! like volley http and retrofit! , use any one ! okhttp along retrofit is a solution easy one actually and are you using too heavy images in your drawables! try using xml resources there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your release build type, be sure to have `shrinkResources` set to true. `minifyEnabled` is not enough.

You're including Glide and Picasso. Use either one, not both.

You're including Volley and Retrofit. Use either one, not both.

`android-pdf-viewer` is notoriously big. See explanation and workaround at https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#why-resulting-apk-is-so-big
This is the biggest reason why your apk is so huge.

Inside your proguard:

```
# ALSO REMEMBER KEEPING YOUR MODEL CLASSES
-keep class com.your.package.model.** { *; }
```

The above is not needed.

Google's libraries often ship with their own embedded proguard rules; your proguard rules for cardview, android support design libraries etc are probably not needed.

Also review your drawables. Use xml drawables whenever you can, and JPEGs for backgrounds that don't require transparency. Try the webP format also.

Comment: That's the best library so far imo. As per suggestion, split your apk. Or don't include a built-in pdf reader if your requirements allow it. Raising an intent to view a PDF file is a lot simpler too.